How to Access WiFi Network Statistics from a Windows Host in a Docker Container?
I'm developing a Node.js application within a Docker container that requires access to network statistics from a Windows host. I have been using the systeminformation package to retrieve this data. While this setup works correctly on Windows directly, I encounter issues when trying to detect WiFi networks from within the Docker container.
Attempts Made:

Host Network Configuration: I attempted to use --net=host in my Docker run command to access the host’s network interfaces directly. This approach works well on Linux; however, it fails on Windows as Docker does not support the --net=host option in the same way.

Question:
Does anyone have experience or suggestions on how to effectively access host network statistics, specifically WiFi networks, from a Docker container running on Windows? Are there alternative network modes or any specific configurations that could facilitate this access?
Thanks in advance for any help or insights!
